# I'm trying to move a cube on the screen according to the data from a csvfile, but it's not working. Can someone help me with this code?

Tags: csv, position, gameobject

I'm trying to move a cube on the screen according to the data from a csvfile, but it's not working. Can someone help me with this code?

using UnityEngine;

```
public class LeitorCSV : MonoBehaviour

{
    public GameObject cubeTest;
    public TextAsset csvFile;

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        ReadCSV();
    }

    private void ReadCSV()
    {
        string[] records = csvFile.text.Split('\n');
        for (int i = 1; i < records.Length; i++)
        {
            string[] fields = records[i].Split(',');
            cubeTest.transform.Translate(float.Parse(fields[1]), 
float.Parse(fields[2]), float.Parse(fields[3]));
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried it that way and not work either.

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using System.IO;
using System.Collections.Generic;

public class leitorCSV2 : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject cubeTest;
    public TextAsset csvFile;

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        readCSV();


    }

    void readCSV()
    {
        string[] records = csvFile.text.Split('\n');

        for (int i = 1; i < records.Length; i++)
        {
            string[] fields = records[i].Split(',');

            float x = float.TryParse(fields[1], out x) ? x : 0;
            float y = float.TryParse(fields[2], out y) ? y : 0;
            float z = float.TryParse(fields[3], out z) ? z : 0;



            cubeTest.transform.Translate(new Vector3(x, y, z) * 
Time.deltaTime);
        }
    }
}
```